# What are the French words he is saying?

Tags: grammaire

At timestamp 4:51 in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8e5GK-owAKQ&t=285s), someone in the background said something like "porto momotar" two times. What is he saying exactly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is not really on [topic on French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Since you are not new to Stack Exchange your 101 reputation gives you [the privilege](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to participate in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=french.stackexchange.com) where all sorts of off topic questions are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I hear ***On tombe, on repart*** (you fall, you start over).

It's probably better to ask this kind of question in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).